# What's the best workflow for an Azure virtual machine (Windows)?

Tags: windows, node.js, mongodb, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I'm developing a Socket.IO application with a MongoDB database. For various reasons I am developing the application to run on a Windows virtual machine within Azure. Setting everything up was fairly painless and I now have a basic application within the cloud. However, I am unable to find a comfortable workflow. I want to be able to push changes to the virtual machine (as if I was on *nix system using git) and I'm not sure how best to do this.

Comment: maybe this help you http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2012/06/three-ways-of-deploying-nodejs-apps-to.html

Comment: That was a great link although none of those solutions quite fit my situation. Since this is a solo project, I think I'll end up using powershell to remote in and copy files / do administrative work.

Answer (score 2):

So you can use Visual Studio to develop along with Github for Windows.

For something familiar to Linux, you may want to try Cloud9 IDE, which is an IDE in a browser that also makes it easy to connect to your github or bitbucket accounts. It actually supports the basic git commands along with some basic debugging.

The Cloud9 IDE is not quite as advanced as Visual Studio. But it's very focused for node.js and I have been enjoying it quite a bit for my personal projects.